# Django __init__ QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, overwrite

essentially the idea is that every method in a specific `QuerySet` will have to use a variable. So define that variable in the `__init__` seems to be a good approach:

```
class SomeQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def __init__(self,something):
        self.something = something
        #what goes here???
    #...
```

now I know that the way Django works, the `QuerySet` must have an `__init__` with some very important code, and this would overwrite it. **What would I need to add to this `__init__` so that it would not disrupt the `QuerySet`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `super(SomeQuerySet, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` whilst changing your `__init__` method to `def __init__(self, something, *args, **kwargs)`. The `QuerySet` itself is using parameters in the `__init__` method so you need to pass them to it.

Comment: wouldn't `something` be in the `*args` though?